# ipv6 proxy forward result in bad request

Tags: proxy, ipv6

I've configured the apache httpd server to act as a proxy forwarder. Following is my conf file details

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:9999
Listen [::]:9999
<VirtualHost *:9999>

SSLEngine off
SSLProxyEngine On
SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/ca.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/ca.key

ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/rest/v1/ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/rest/v1/
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm using the curl client

for IPv4:

> > curl http://192.168.56.11/rest/v1/ --proxy 0.0.0.0:9999 -v

It is working fine and I'm getting the proper result

for IPv6:

> > curl -6 http://fe80::2:0:9:1%eth1/rest/v1/ --proxy [::]:9999 -v

With ipv6 the call is failing and I'm getting response code as "400". Following error message is seen in error_log for this ipv6 request

**[error] [client ::1] request failed: error reading the headers**

Actually the target server is Jetty Server but I'm seeing the value as " Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)" on failure cases. Also there is no log for call reaching the destination. It is actually failing in the proxy.

Comment: When using an IPv6 address in a URI, you need to surround the address with brackets: `[` and `]`. I don't think you can use a link-local address in a URI, either.

Comment: I'm not even sure what using the _unspecified address_ (whether `0.0.0.0` for IPv4 or `::` for IPv6) for the `--proxy` parameter in `curl` should _mean._ Using the unspecified address in the Apache config means "bind to all addresses on local interfaces you can find." But what should it do on the `curl` command line? Search for a proxy on all addresses on all interfaces until you find one? You should certainly use a real address there. And I second @RonMaupin: Using a link local address in a URL will probably not work as the `%` has a special meaning in a URL (and you're missing the brackets).

Answer (score 2):

Your `VirtualHost` is only set up to process IPv4 connections.

```
<VirtualHost *:9999>
```

You need to set it up to process both IPv4 and IPv6 connections.

```
<VirtualHost *:9999 [::]:9999>
```

Comment: Michael Thanks for your response. I've changed the Virtual Host but still not successful. Any other thoughts ?